# MongoDB: Simple query issue

Tags: java, mongodb, database

currently I'm trying to learn dealing with MongoDB in Java. I created the collection "plots" and inserted a document:

```
final Document plotObj = new Document();
        plotObj.put(DataKey.PLOT_UUID.getKey(), plot.getUniqueId());
        plotObj.put(DataKey.REGION_ID.getKey(), plot.getRegionId());
        plotObj.put(DataKey.REGION_WORLD.getKey(), plot.getRegionWorld());
        plotObj.put(DataKey.REGION_OWNER.getKey(), plot.getPlotOwner().isPresent() ? plot.getPlotOwner() : null);
        plotObj.put(DataKey.PLOT_TRUSTED.getKey(), new BasicDBList().addAll(plot.getTrusted()));
        this.collection.insertOne(plotObj);
```

"DataKey.PLOT_UUID.getKey()" represents a String. "plot.getUniqueId()" represents a java.util.UUID. After inserting this Document, I want to query it:

```
public boolean hasPlot(UUID plotId){
    final BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(DataKey.PLOT_UUID.getKey(), new BasicDBObject("$eq", plotId));
    return this.collection.find(query).iterator().hasNext();
}
```

However this methods always returns false event though the Document was successfully inserted.

Maybe this problem can be fixed with ease but nevertheless: thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Is this maybe an effect of the 'near real-time' behaviour of mongodb? I've read about it but cannot find the link any more. In mongodb it is possible that the mongodb-query doesn't find an object that was just inserted. Maybe you could set a timer and test your query with a little delay?

Comment: Even after restarting the application, it returns false. I need this method to make sure whether I have to insert or update a document.

Comment: So there seems to be only two obvious options left: The plotId you pass to your method isn't the plotId that you saved in the database ? or: your library doesn't handle uuid's the right way?

Comment: Can you show what document is inserted and `this.collection` value?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you don't need the $eq
just write

```
new BasicDBObject(DataKey.PLOT_UUID.getKey(), plotId));
```